# Power factor problem

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework, power-factor-correction

I need help solving this problem in my mind, so if anyone had a similar problem it would help me.

In order to make a higher power factor on a receiver, we connect a capacitor of appropriate capacity in parallel to that receiver.
If we have a higher capacitance of the capacitor, we will also have a higher power factor.

Circuit looks like this:

[image]

First case:

```
R=470 Ω
L=100mH
U=5V effective value
f=2kHz
I=2.81mA
C=100nF
```

Second case:

```
R=470 Ω
L=100mH
f=2kHz
U=5V effective value
I=5.48mA
C=147nF
```

This is where the problem arises.

In the first case for a current of `2.81mA`
and a capacitor capacitance of `100nF`, I obtained that the power factor `k = 0.42`.

In the second case for a current of `5.48mA` and a higher capacitance of `147nF` I got that the power factor `k = 0.22`.

What interests me is: Why did the power factor decrease if we used more capacitance in the second case? I think it's because of the current, but I don't understand how?

Answer (score 2):

Well, in order to find a general formula for the power factor we first take a look at the power factor formula. The power factor formula is given by:

$$\Delta:=\cos\left(\varphi\right)\tag1$$

Where \$\varphi=\left|\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}\right)-\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}\right)\right|=\left|\arg\left(\frac{\underline{\text{V}}}{\underline{\text{I}}}\right)\right|=\left|\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}\right)\right|\$.

So, for your case we get:

$$\Delta=\cos\left|\arg\left(\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\space\text{||}\space\left(\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)\right)\right|\tag2$$

Where \$\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta}\$.

So, we can simplify:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\Delta&=\cos\left|\arg\left(\frac{\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\cdot\left(\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)}{\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}\right)\right|\\
\\
&=\cos\left|\arg\left(\frac{\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}{1-\omega^2\text{CL}+\text{j}\omega\text{CR}}\right)\right|\\
\\
&=\cos\left|\arg\left(\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)-\arg\left(1-\omega^2\text{CL}+\text{j}\omega\text{CR}\right)\right|\\
\\
&=\cos\left|\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}}\right)-\arg\left(1-\omega^2\text{CL}+\text{j}\omega\text{CR}\right)\right|\\
\\
&=\begin{cases}
\cos\left|\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}}\right)-\frac{\pi}{2}\right|\space\space\space&\text{if}\space1-\omega^2\text{CL}=0\\
\\
\cos\left|\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\text{CR}}{1-\omega^2\text{CL}}\right)\right|\space\space\space&\text{if}\space1-\omega^2\text{CL}>0\\
\\
\cos\left|\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}}\right)-\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\frac{\omega^2\text{CL}-1}{\omega\text{CR}}\right)\right)\right|\space\space\space&\text{if}\space1-\omega^2\text{CL}<0
\end{cases}\\
\\
&=\begin{cases}
\frac{\omega\text{L}}{\sqrt{\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}}\space\space\space&\text{if}\space1-\omega^2\text{CL}=0\\
\\
\frac{\text{R}}{\sqrt{\left(\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2\right)\left(1+\omega^2\text{C}\left(\text{CR}^2+\text{L}\left(\omega^2\text{CL}-2\right)\right)\right)}}\space\space\space&\text{if}\space1-\omega^2\text{CL}>0\\
\\
\frac{\text{R}}{\sqrt{\left(\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2\right)\left(1+\omega^2\text{C}\left(\text{CR}^2+\text{L}\left(\omega^2\text{CL}-2\right)\right)\right)}}\space\space\space&\text{if}\space1-\omega^2\text{CL}<0
\end{cases}\\
\\
&=\begin{cases}
\frac{\omega\text{L}}{\sqrt{\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}}\space\space\space&\text{if}\space1-\omega^2\text{CL}=0\\
\\
\frac{\text{R}}{\sqrt{\left(\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2\right)\left(1+\omega^2\text{C}\left(\text{CR}^2+\text{L}\left(\omega^2\text{CL}-2\right)\right)\right)}}\space\space\space&\text{if}\space1-\omega^2\text{CL}>0\space\wedge\space1-\omega^2\text{CL}<0
\end{cases}\\
\\
&=\begin{cases}
\frac{\omega\text{L}}{\sqrt{\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}}\space\space\space&\text{if}\space\omega=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{CL}}}\\
\\
\frac{\text{R}}{\sqrt{\left(\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2\right)\left(1+\omega^2\text{C}\left(\text{CR}^2+\text{L}\left(\omega^2\text{CL}-2\right)\right)\right)}}\space\space\space&\text{if}\space0\leq\omega<\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{CL}}}\space\wedge\space\omega>\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{CL}}}
\end{cases}
\end{split}\tag3
\end{equation}

Now, let's analyze your two cases:

1. We can see that \$1-\omega^2\text{CL}=1-\left(2\pi\cdot2\cdot1000\right)^2\cdot100\cdot10^{-9}\cdot100\cdot10^3=1-160000\pi^2<0\$. So:
   $$\Delta=\frac{11750}{\sqrt{\left(2209+1600 \pi ^2\right) \left(62500-17791 \pi ^2+1600 \pi ^4\right)}}\approx0.423502\tag4$$
2. We can see that \$1-\omega^2\text{CL}=1-\left(2\pi\cdot2\cdot1000\right)^2\cdot147\cdot10^{-9}\cdot100\cdot10^3=1-235200\pi^2<0\$. So:
   $$\Delta=\frac{58750}{\sqrt{\left(2209+1600 \pi ^2\right) \left(1562500-591759 \pi ^2+78400 \pi ^4\right)}}\approx0.238927\tag5$$

---

**Edit**

Plotting the power factor, we can see that:

[image]

The maximum occurs when:

$$\text{C}=\frac{1}{2209000+1600000 \pi ^2}\approx5.55544\cdot10^{-8}\space\text{F}\tag6$$

Answer (score 0):

In scenario 1 using 100 nF, the power factor is leading i.e. there is too much capacitance for a power factor of unity at 2 kHz. In scenario 2 you use more capacitance and therefore the PF is leading even more and, as a result, the power factor drops even more.

I established this by considering what the natural resonant frequency is of the 1st scenario: -

$$f_n = \dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}} = \dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{0.1H\times 0.1\mu F}} = 1592 \text{ Hz}$$

Clearly, with 2 kHz applied, the capacitive reactance is going to dominate hence, both scenarios are leading power factors.

> *If we have a higher capacitance of the capacitor, we will also have a
> higher power factor.*

Only up to the point when PF = 1 then, as you increase capacitance, PF gets lower (but leading). If you want a more precise analysis, try this: -

[image]

The upper graph is current into the network of the inductor, resistor and parallel capacitor. It indicates that minimum current is obtained when f = 1570 Hz. Circuit: -

[image]

And clearly, best PF is obtained when the phase angle of current is zero: -

[image]

This happens at 1405 Hz.

If you need to know the capacitance needed to get unity PF at 2 kHz, it's 55.55 nF: -

[image]